# Qt: фокус lineEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Есть форма в QtCreator, на ней lineEdit и кнопки. Как сделать, чтобы lineEdit всегда оставался в фокусе (чтобы каретка мигала), независимо от нажатий на кнопки, перемещения или любых других действий с формой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать свой "жадный" виджет, который ни с кем фокусом делиться не будет.

```
class LineEdit : public QLineEdit{
public:
    explicit LineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0):
        QLineEdit(parent)
    {}
protected:
    void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *){
        setFocus();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробоуйте вызвать у кнопки метод после создания:

button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);

Или выставить соотвествующее поле в QtCreator. Тем самым кнопку не будет получать фокус.

Comment: Попробовал, кнопка фокус не получает, но lineEdit все равно его теряет.

Comment: Видимо какой-то другой виджит получает фокус. Но по клику на кнопке вы можете возращать фокус lineEdit-у. Либо понять какой из виджетов получает фокус. Возможно это ваше главное окно.

Answer (score 4):

А может быть, добавить перехват нажатия клавиши на клавиатуре главному окну и вписать туда передачу фокуса lineEdite?

"Мигать" курсор не будет, но по идее можно добиться того, чтобы текст всегда вписывался туда, куда нужно, где до этого ни был фокус.

```
void Widget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *ev)
{
lineEdit->setFocus();
lineEdit->setText(ev->text());
}

void Widget::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *ev)
{
// или так
}
```

`Widget` тут надо заменить вашей главной формой

Answer (score 1):

нужно поймать сигнал editingFinished() и обработать его своим слотом, который будет устанавливать фокус: ui->lineEdit->setFocus().